# GLFW window glfwSwapBuffers() really really slow?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I wanted to build a game engine in c++ and OpenGL for the first time. I have done it c#. Now i use GLFW and GLEW. But when i make a simple window and measure the fps, it is already slow. Without even rendering anything.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include "tortoise4.h"
#include "src/util/File.h"
#include "src/util//Timer.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
LOG("Main");
system("color 0a");

using namespace tortoise4;

Timer time;
float timer = 0.0f;
unsigned int frames = 0;

if (!glfwInit()) return 0;

GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(1920, 1080, "Test", NULL, NULL);
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) return 0;

while (true) {//!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)
    //int w, h;
    //glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &w, &h);
    //glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    //glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    //glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    //glfwPollEvents();

    frames++;
    if (time.elapsed() - timer > 1.0f) {
        timer += 1.0f;
        printf("%d fps\n", frames);
        frames = 0;
    }
}

glfwDestroyWindow(window);
glfwTerminate();

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

}

When i comment out glfwSwapBuffers(Window); i get an absurd FPS, which is expected because the loops does nothing. When i call glfwSwapBuffers(Window); The fps drops to 70fps for 1080p. The fps is 30 for 1620p and 200 for 540p.

So when i increase the resolution i get a lower fps. This is to be expected when you render things, but this is just an empty window! I cant get an empty 1620p window at 60 fps?

The gpu seems to be at 30% workload when i swap buffers, while it shouldnt do much?

My specs are:
CPU: i7 4810mq
GPU: gtx 870m
RAM: 8 gb

I play many games just fine, it should we able to handle a black screen...
I tried it in x64/x86/debug/release modes. same results.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: A function called _glfwGetWGLContext seems to need a lot of cpu time.
EDIT: This issue seems only the case when i use my dedicated gpu(GTX 870M)!
when i use the integrated one(hd 4600) it doesnt clear the screen the the right colour..

Comment: Please show how `Timer` is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

The framerates you stated are suspiciously close to standard display framerates and most likely your program is simply synchronized to display refresh (V-Sync). V-Sync can be disabled in the driver or using OpenGL extensions, however it is strongly recommended to keep V-Sync enabled.

When you switch resolutions, do you switch the actual resolution of the picture sent to the display device or do you change the window size?

Comment: I change the size of the window. If i change the viewport nothing happans. It is not vsync, if have disabled it and called glfwSwapInterval(-1); I just went back to an older engine in c# and it has the same problem. with glGetString() i confirmed i use my gtx 870m and i have an opengl version of 4.5.0. But then again i can play games just fine on 1080p and they must swap buffers too.

Comment: A swap interval of -1 doesn't disable vsync, it enables "adaptive vsync" via [EXT_swap_control_tear](https://khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/WGL_EXT_swap_control_tear.txt).